# Mixpanel Segmentation Queries API Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, mixpanel

I am trying to import mixpanel data into google spreadsheet using the script editor in google sheets.

I used this script: https://github.com/melissaguyre/mixpanel-segmentation-google-spreadsheets

But I have problems formulating my queries, in the script at this part:

```
var API_PARAMETERS = {
  'Sheet 1' :  [ 'event', 'where', 'general', 'day' ],
};
```

In mixpanel I have an event called "order created" that can be done by Customer Type A, Customer Type B, Customer Type C. In mixpanel I choose that by adding "Customer Type" and select "contains" and choose whatever customer type i am interested in. Who would i translate that into the correct queries in Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
var API_PARAMETERS = {
  'Sheet 1' :  [ 'order created', '(properties["Customer Type"])=="Customer Type A" or (properties["Customer Type"])=="Customer Type B"', 'general', 'day' ]
};
```

Works fine here.